# Searching in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, filter

I have some boxes div class and I would like when the users enter anything in the search box, it will display those boxes and those boxes only (filters it). The current code will remove all the boxes before displaying what the user enters in the searchbox. Thanks!

```
<!-- Search box -->
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  />
<!-- Search button-->
<input type="button"  id="searchTest" value="Search"/>


<!-- Searching for the ID that the user enter -->
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>

$('#searchTest').click(function() {

    // removes all the div class before displaying the results
    $('div[id*=ID_]').css('display', 'none');

    //display only whatever the user's entered
        $('div[id*=ID_]').filter(bla).css('display', 'block');
    });

    </script>



    <!-- Test boxes that needs filtering-->
    <div class="color1" id="USEID_company1_user1_Location1">
        <p> test</p>
    </div> 

    <div class="color2" id="USEID_company2_user2_Location2">
        <p> test</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy when you get to know jQuery's [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the basics. Adjust it to your own liking.

```js
var $elements = $('.element');

function search(value) {
    if (value == '') {
        $elements.filter(':hidden').show(); // show all hidden elements
        return;
    }
  
    $matches = $elements.filter('[data-label*="' + value.toLowerCase() + '"]'); // find search matches

    $elements.show().not($matches).hide(); // hide elements that don't match
}

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    search(this.value);
});
```

```css
#search {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.element {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search the DOM..." />

<div class="element" data-label="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="element" data-label="world">World</div>
<div class="element" data-label="car">Car</div>
<div class="element" data-label="train">Train</div>
<div class="element" data-label="bicycle">Bicycle</div>
<div class="element" data-label="motor">Motor</div>
<div class="element" data-label="plane">Plane</div>
<div class="element" data-label="surfboard">Surfboard</div>
<div class="element" data-label="skateboard">Skateboard</div>
<div class="element" data-label="hovercraft">Hovercraft</div>
```

You might noticed this `*=` piece of code, which is the [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). It selects all elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring. In our case the substring represents a search string.

Elements are filtered out based on the `data-label` attribute. I feel like it was brought to life for this kind of functionalities. You could filter on ID's too if you want.

Last but not least; you might want to consider debouncing the `search()` function to prevent having to search/manipulate the DOM every time the client pressed a key. These operations are pretty resource-intensive.